# The **equals** in Set interface

Tags: java, collections, set

As we know two `Set` instances are equal *iff they contain the same elements*, BUT is it possible to have the same element in two different sets (`Set` interface can not contain duplicate element)?

Comment: i'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Please rephrase, possibly with a code sample.

Comment: We use the ** same element** for equality,but as I know there is no duplicate element in Set interface.So how we can use equal operation???

Comment: Two different sets can contain the same elements, if that's what you're asking. If it's not, try making more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct sets have no affect on one another. Set A can contain '123456', and Set B can also contain '123456' - the prohibition on duplicates is for a single instance, not across instances.

Equality for two sets implies that their contents are identical.

Comment: There are all sorts of problems that come up with defining "equality". I believe the java.uti.set subclasses all use the objects .equals method to check if one object is equal to another. Another way to define this is to use the == operator in Java, which is what I believe the .equals method defaults to unless it is overwritten. There are quite a few subtleties with sets to consider without even going into Bertrand Russels set theory paradox.

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing the elements inside a Set with each other to detect if they are equal, you are comparing the Elements of Set1 with the elements of Set2.

Answer (score 1):

the equals method is described pretty well [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).